# Elasticsearch denormalized data query

Tags: javascript, json, elasticsearch, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I haven't found any examples of elastic search with relational data.

For example:

```
{
    part: {
        -KbH7E4YBTHvpRVo17P4: {
            description: "Macbook Pro Late 2016 3.3 GHZ"
            id_category: "-KbEGUZU9In8XcWOtNbu"
            id_subcategory: "-KbEGVWkmvycYEAiHAEj"
            manufacturer: "Apple"
        }
    },
    category: {
        -KbEGUZU9In8XcWOtNbu: {
            name: "Computer"
        }
    },
    subcategory: {
        -KbEGVWkmvycYEAiHAEj: {
            name: "Laptop"
        }
    }
}
```

How do I create a query which takes a search string and be able to search the part, category and subcategory and return the part found.  So if they search "app" the manufacturer will respond with a hit.  If they type "comp" the category will hit and the part will be returned.  Same with subcategory.

Using the firebase database, they urge against nesting data, so I have denormalized everything but seems like every example on the elasticsearch website is all with nested data.

I know I could add in the category and subcategory names into part but then I have to keep up with them if they change.

I have the same issues with partItems where I have multiple partItems per part and those are linked to part and order so I need to keep part and partItems separated.

Here is the mappings:

```
// http://localhost:9200/firebase

{
  "firebase": {
    "aliases": {

    },
    "mappings": {
      "part": {
        "properties": {
          "description": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "id_category": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "id_subcategory": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "manufacturer": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "partitems": {
            "properties": {
              "-KbHaDD6aEwMYBW-Kj_Q": {
                "type": "boolean"
              },
              "-KbISzbdULqNRYflYrFt": {
                "type": "boolean"
              },
              "-KbJyfACXPL44FYQAwne": {
                "type": "boolean"
              },
              "-KbK5STKmY-3NEE-uher": {
                "type": "boolean"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "partitem": {
        "properties": {
          "cost": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "id_part": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "id_vendor": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "part_number": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "quantity": {
            "type": "long"
          }
        }
      },
      "subcategory": {
        "properties": {
          "-KbEGVWkmvycYEAiHAEj": {
            "properties": {
              "id_category": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "name": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "-KbEbSI2NohHad3dcvju": {
            "properties": {
              "id_category": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "name": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "category": {
        "properties": {
          "-KbEGUZU9In8XcWOtNbu": {
            "properties": {
              "name": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "subcategories": {
                "properties": {
                  "-KbEGVWkmvycYEAiHAEj": {
                    "type": "boolean"
                  },
                  "-KbEbSI2NohHad3dcvju": {
                    "type": "boolean"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "creation_date": "1485328359842",
        "number_of_shards": "5",
        "number_of_replicas": "1",
        "uuid": "xxx",
        "version": {
          "created": "5010299"
        },
        "provided_name": "firebase"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How does your documents look like in ES?

Comment: please upload your schema mappings for all the relational objects to support your question.

Comment: I ended up just making a searchable object in the DB which has all the information I need and I can search that node for what I need.  Just copying data that I really don't think should be duplicated like that.

Comment: I'm not sure it's the most optimal way of doing things, but if it serves your purpose, that's good